# Starting Angular application as a default of a NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface

I have a NodeJS application and an Angular 6 as a frontend.

The project looks like:

```
-> Node Project
   ---> src 
       ---> Client_App (Anuglar)
```

To run the application, I need to follow those commands and start the server and angular separately, like:

```
-> node start
-> cd src/Client_App
-> ng serve
```

I need to start the two application with one single command or to add my dist file of Angular to be run at the start of my NodeJS, which is using Jade right now.

I am still new to NodeJS and still don't know how to configure it.

Anybody can help? Thanks

### Edited:

I have tried now to add the dist folder to my views folder and run it within the app.js

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app_server/views/ngapp/index.html'));
});
```

But I am receiving the error, that my .js and .css folders are not found:
[image]

Comment: What do you want to start ? A server in production mode or a local server to test your application ? Seems unclear, you talk about `ng serve` and `dist` folder, and both are totally different. What is your end goal ?

Comment: Well, my end goal is to be able to copy my project, give it to someone and run it on his machine with a single step. This is what my Uni asks for. I know it is a bit strange, but they wanted that way. I have to configure the NodeJS to run the Angular as a startup project. Whether the real angular project or the dist file.

Comment: Not strange at all ! This is a common use case in companies. Have you considered using Docker for that ?

Comment: No, I should provide a .zip file that works on others' machine, with the node_module folder also. I normally work with Build Server and DevOps, that is why I am a little lost with these stuff.

Comment: Okay then. Let me answer you quickly.

Comment: please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your application with the CLI `ng build --prod`, you get a `dist` folder : this folder contains **all of your application**, bundled into different files (feel free to look at them).

To be able to create a .ZIP file with that, you will need two things :

- this `dist` folder
- an http server

You have the first one, but not the second one.

All you need is a very simple server. For instance, [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) on NPM can do that. By installing it as a dev dependency, you could create a command in your `package.json` file

```
"deploy-locally": "http-server ./dist"
```

And now run it with

```
npm run deploy-locally
```

Or even better,

```
"start": "http-server ./dist"
```

And run with

```
npm start
```

If you don't want to use a NPM package (or forced to use NodeJS), simply create a basic http server in a JS file and run it with your command line (sorry, can't help on that, not into nodeJS right now).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't solve the problem of a single command line. Because I still have to start my dist file separately instead of my actual angular app, correct?

Comment: Nope. Your dist folder **IS** your Angular application. You give the zip to someone, they unzip it, and they just run `npm start` and your application is running on local mode.

Comment: But they still need to run the NodeJS separately as well. They will get a .zip folder from me containing the whole project including the NodeJS. The supervisor has to unzip it, open the command line, run "node start" and the application should start the node and the angular as a view. This is my goal.

Comment: Oh ! my bad. Probably something like `app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});` then : give the path to the index file in your dist folder, and your application will be served and accessible on your server.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I've tried. But I received the error shown up there in the question after the edit. That the project cannot find the files.

Comment: Well of course, you're giving the wrong path (and no to a dist folder I assume). Try building your app and using the path I gave previously, this should work

Comment: It is the same. I have rebuilt it using: ng build --prod and added this: res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app_client/dist/aan/index.html'));
he found the index.html but with the same error that shown up there.

Comment: Sorry, could you post the error as text ? I can't see images because of my proxy.

Comment: First one: GET http://localhost:3000/styles.8b73ebc8df1bb4d573fd.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Second one: GET http://localhost:3000/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Styles are supposed to be bundled into a JS file, it's strange that you have an error on this ... Would you mind sharing your source code so that I can try it on local mode ?

Comment: I don't mind, but unfortunately I cannot. Because it is hosted in the Uni DevOps with limited access.

Comment: I did it. The problem was the path of the files. He is trying to access the files in public folder, but they are in the public/aan.  So, I've added them to the app app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/aan'))); then it works, I have to fix the routing now. Thanks a lot. I will mark this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new route and pass in app.route as express.static as below,

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

make sure, u have build version of angular application by running this command,

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

You would need express to install in this case. `express` has amazing ways to handle all this